# Trying to connect to local data base with Httppost

Tags: java, php, android

im am trying to get user data from my Date base hosted with wamp.
I sent a post request to an php file which return a json object but the app gets stuck in HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(request);

This is my code:

```
private void obtenerJson() {
    EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);

    String nombreIngresado = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
    String passwordIngresado = password.getText().toString().trim();

    List<NameValuePair> datos = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    datos.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", nombreIngresado));
    datos.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordIngresado));

    HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/myfiles/myrequest.php");
    BufferedReader lector =null;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

    try {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(datos));
            HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entidad = response.getEntity();                    
            if (entidad != null) {
                String resultado = EntityUtils.toString(entidad, "utf-8");
            }
            lector = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String linea = "";
            String separadora = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while ((linea = lector.readLine()) != null){

            stringBuffer.append(linea + separadora);
        }
        lector.close();
        interpretarJSon(stringBuffer.toString(), nombreIngresado, passwordIngresado);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The code below HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(request); doesn't matter.
The thing is that when I send the request, it return nothing. I use a Log.d to show the response content, but It has nothing to show.

This is my php code:

```
 <?php include('funciones.php'); 
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];

$result = getSQLResultSet("SELECT nombre, password 
FROM  `usuario` where nombre=".$nombre."");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            foreach ($row as $var => $comparar){

                if($nombre == $var ){
                    $nombreok = true;
                }
                if($pass == $var){
                    $passok = true;
                }

                if($nombreok && $passok){
                    $devolver[] = $row;
                }
            }           
        }
        echo json_encode($devolver);
?>
```

This is the code from funciones.php:

```
<?php
function getSQLResultSet($commando){
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "basededatos");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

 $var = $mysqli->execute($commando);

    //return $mysqli->store_result();

$mysqli->close();
return $var;
}
?>
```

I think I might be using a wrong ip, or the problem is in my php code.
I will translate the code if necessary.
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately it's pretty much impossible to remotely figure out problems with WAMP connections.  As for your code, it looks like you might be trying to do network operations on the main thread.  You need to use a background Thread somehow, usually an AsyncTask.  Also note that  `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated for Android 5.1 (API 22). Take a look at this blog post I wrote recently, I think it will help: http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html

Comment: I forgot to say that I am running this in a class that extends AsyncTask, I will check the DefaultHttpClient.

Comment: Ok, that is good then.  In that case, there is likely nothing wrong in your code, on a quick glance it looks ok.  Just realize that it won't work on Android 5.1.  It's probably a problem connecting to your local database, which unfortunately is very hard to remotely debug.  Good luck!

Comment: try to open your ip in android browser to check connection